# Downloading metadata from Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

unable to get access to my metadata on the new Firebase. Able to get download of article and have them display.

```
storageRef.child(article).metadataWithCompletion { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("error getting metadata")
        }else{

            let metadata1 = FIRStorageMetadata()
           let nameMeta = metadata1.downloadURLs

        print("nameMeta is \(nameMeta)")
        }
```

output display:
nameMeta is nil

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't create a new metatada instance, you should use the one already provided in the closure.

```
else {
  let downloadUrl = metadata.downloadUrl()
  print(downloadUrl)
}
```